# Change the href="favicon2.ico" in javascript when the querystring is changed

Tags: javascript

I have this code in silverlight application in the `default.aspx` :

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">   
  <link id="link1" rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon1.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
  <title id="Title1" >hello</title>
```

I need to change the `href="favicon2.ico"` in JavaScript when the querystring is changed.

I tried to write this, but it's not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if( Request.QueryString ("user"). Equals("true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
    document.title="hi user"; 
    document.getElementById('link1').href = ('favicon2.ico');
  }
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Next time take a look at the preview box before posting, at least ensure that the code is properly formatted instead of a mangled mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add JavaScript function

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Change your code as purely JavaScript (You are mixing C# and JavaScript)

```
if(getParameterByName("user").toLowerCase() == "true")
{
   document.title="hi user"; 

   var newImage = new Image();
   newImage.src = 'favicon2.ico?_=' + new Date().getTime();
   document.getElementById('link1').href = newImage.src;    
}
```

Update:

```
if(getParameterByName("user").toLowerCase() == "true")
{
   document.title="hi user"; 
   changeFavicon('favicon2.ico');
}

function changeFavicon(src) {
var link = document.createElement('link'),
oldLink = document.getElementById('link1');
link.id = 'link1';
link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
link.href = src;
if (oldLink) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(oldLink);
}
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: thanks!!! this code is working: if(getParameterByName("user").toLowerCase() == "true"). -the title changed!!! but the icon not changed, with this code:document.getElementById('link1').href = 'favicon2.ico';
why?

Comment: document.getElementById('link1').href = 'favicon2.ico';            - it works well, but only in chrome. how can it work in Internet Explorer?

Comment: @user2474172, I have updated answer ideally provide complete path of favicon2

Comment: thanks! but it all works only in chrome, do you have another option that works in explorer? it is a lot help for me!!!

Comment: @user2474172, I think you are using C# in back end, try once from there

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this in your code

```
document.getElementById('link1').href = "favicon2.ico";
```

Comment: Doesn't really make any difference. `('str') === "str"`

Comment: I think too! ('string)== "string"